# Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Api\Payer' not found codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fatal-error, paypal

I uploaded the paypal php sdk to my codeigniter app inside the libraries/paypal folder.
In the same folder I create a paypal.php file and inside it I insert this code:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/common.php';

use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

class Paypal{
    function createPayment(){
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");
        //....
    }
}
```

but when I call this function in my controller I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Api\Payer' not found in '....'
```

I don't understand why instead common.php is imported correctly.
In my app I also have the Facebook sdk and I created the same structure to use it and it works

Comment: Check the namespace you are using is same as the one declared in PayPal SDK

Comment: Thanks! I was sure I wrote it, but I didn't...

Comment: Now it says that he doesn't find class Paypal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is to follow these steps.

1. Download the SDK using composer.
2. Upload the vendor directory into codeIgniter Application root.

Then in the index.php file put this line

**include "./vendor/autoload.php";**

Now you can access the Paypal SDK and its dependent libraries easily.